# How to do WHERE IN in linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a Blog object which has a list of tag objects (`List<Tag>`).

I'm trying to create a method that takes a list of tags and returns a list of blogs that contain all the tags in the passed in list.

I was able to make a method that will return a list of blogs if it matches one tag, but not a list of tags.

to do that I have this

```
entities.Blogs.Where(b => b.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tagName))
```

But I can't figure out how to do something like this

```
entities.Blogs.Where(b => b.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == tags[0] AND t.Name == tags[1] AND t.Name == tags[2] etc.......))
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!

I'm using LINQ to Entities

Comment: Do you mean that you're looking for blogs which contain at least one tag from the tags array?  Or are you trying to find blogs which contain all tags from the tags array?

Comment: I think that's going to make it so that it only returns something that has a tag that matches everything in your passed in list.

Comment: I'm trying to find blogs that contain all tags from the tags array

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're using LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logically, I think you want something like:

```
entities.Blogs.Where(b => tags.All(t => b.Tags.Any(bt => bt.Name == t)))
```

Alternatively:

```
HashSet<string> tagNames = new HashSet<string>(tags);
return entities.Blogs
               .Where(b => tagNames.IsSubsetOf(b.Tags.Select(x => x.Name)));
```

If this is using LINQ to Entities, I doubt that this will work - but it should work if you're just using LINQ to Objects. Even then, it's not going to be terribly efficient. I suspect there's a more efficient way of doing things, but I can't immediately think of it... it feels like you want a join, but then it gets tricky again.

Comment: Jon Skeet is the MAN! Thank you JS. The first option worked out great.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
List<Tag> tags = GetTags...;
IQueryable<Blog> blogs = entities.Blogs; // start with all
foreach(var tag in tags){
   var thisTag = tag;  //this is needed to prevent a bug
   blogs = blogs.Where(entry=>entry.Tags.Any(entryTag=>entryTag.TagId==thisTag.TagId));
}
return blogs.OrderBy....;
```

This will chain together the Where clauses to require that all the Tags be present for a blog entry to be returned.