# How to do multiple Select Where in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm new in Linq, and I want to convert this sql Query to Linq Format.

This is the SQL format

```
select *
from investorwallets iw
where transactionid in 
(select investordepositid from investordeposits)
or transactionid in
(select withdrawalid from investorwithdrawals)
or transactionid in
(select paymentdistributionid from paymentdistributions)
```

I've looked on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026542/how-to-do-where-in-in-linq) Question too, but no luck for me

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried. I use Linqpad for testing it

```
from iw in  Investorwallets 
where   (
            from id in Investordeposits // I got error from here
            select id.investordepositid
        )
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Add `.Contains(iw.transactionid)`. Then do the similar for other criterias with `||` between and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct is:

```
from iw in investorwallets 
where investordeposits.Any(iten => item.investordepositid == iw.transactionid) ||
      investorwithdrawals.Any(iten => item.withdrawalid == iw.transactionid) ||
      paymentdistributions.Any(item => item.paymentdistributionid == iw.transactionid)
select iw;
```

However you can also union the results and then do `.Contains`:

```
var ids = investorwithdrawals.Select(item => item.investordepositid)
                             .Union(investorwithdrawals.Select(item => item.withdrawalid))
                             .Union(paymentdistributions.Select(item => item.paymentdistributionid));

var result = investorwallets.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.transactionid));
```

Comment: hi dude, will try it, and will update to you soon, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<investorwallet> investorwallets = GetInvestorwallets();
        List<investordeposit> investordeposits = GetInvestordeposits();
        List<investorwithdrawal> investorwithdrawals = GetInvestorwithdrawals();
        List<paymentdistribution> paymentdistributions = GetPaymentdistribution();

        List<investorwallet> newList = investorwallets.Where(x => investordeposits.Any(y=>y.investordepositid == x.transactionid)
                                        || investorwithdrawals.Any(y => y.withdrawalid == x.transactionid)
                                        || paymentdistributions.Any(y => y.paymentdistributionid == x.transactionid)).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the help dude, i have to mark gilad's answer, because he's the first. :)